# where is bootstrap Scaffolding?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am running a python project and I am including bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js (both are version 3.3.7).  I am using pycharm and when I run the project and debug the page and look at the elements, I see the styles that are being applied to the elements.  I am trying to find where to change the color of the navigation menu and the menu items.  I found that by adding background-color to the .navbar that begins on line 4165 of bootstrap.css I can change the navigation background color and I see that in the debugging window that shows the elements and the styles that apply to that element.  One of the elements on the page, the  element has a default color of #337ab7 and the debugger says it comes from scaffolding.less:52.  Where is this coming from?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend you not overwriting the bootstrap CSS. If you want to apply custom styles include them in a seperate file and link it the line after all other CSS files in your script.

Comment: Instead of directly changing bootstrap.css, the convention of BS3 is to create a new stylesheet to be included on the page after the initial library is loaded. See: https://antjanus.com/blog/uncategorized/make-bootstrap-3-theme-proper-way/

Comment: You're seeing a mapping to the CSS pre-processor files ([LESS](http://lesscss.org/) files) that generated the final Bootstrap CSS file. You likely downloaded from the _Download Bootstrap_ link. Download from the _Download source_ link and in that zip file will be the LESS files the debugger points to. The info to compile the LESS is [on the home page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#grunt) of Bootstrap 3.3.7.